# Changes in code from Mysql to Mongodb in search and find_by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

This is my categories controller

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @categories = Category.order(:name).where("name like ?", "%#{params[:term]}%")
    render json: @categories.map(&:name)
  end
end
```

This is my category model

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end
```

This is my product model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category

  def category_name
    category.try(:name)
  end

  def category_name=(name)
    self.category = Category.find_by_name(name) if name.present?
  end
end
```

my product.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  $('#product_category_name').autocomplete
    source: $('#product_category_name').data('autocomplete-source')
```

my form for product is

```
 <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :category_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :category_name, data: {autocomplete_source: categories_path} %>
  </div>
```

here i want to save the id of category in database when i select the name of catogory from search..

Above code is working code for Mysql 
I want to change it for Mongodb Database. I am using Mongoid.
Which part should i change to work in Mongodb ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most definitely would need to modify the way you query Models if you are using MongoDB. The line:

```
@categories = Category.order(:name).where("name like ?", "%#{params[:term]}%")
```

Is SQL-specific. You should convert it to something readable in MongoDB/Mongoid like:

```
@categories = Category.where({:name => /#{params[:term]}/}).order_by(name: 1)
```

Also you will have to replace ActiveRecord with Mongoid. You can refer to [Mongoid's installation instruction](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html) if you are using Mongoid as your ODM.

Comment: Thanks it works for search but it gives this error in model undefined method `find_by_name' for Name:Class

Comment: According to Mongoid's [Google group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mongoid/ca2rob7qbwQ/qp_wx6Ie4jwJ), Mongoid does not support dynamic finders. So I guess you would have to settle down to regular `where` or `find_by`, i.e. `where({:name => name}).first` or `find_by(name: name)`.

Comment: Here i want to save id of category in category_name field. In name params name of category is passed. How can i send its id in the database instead of its name?

Comment: I'm not sure I get it. You mean something like: `@category.category_name = Category.find_by(name: name).id`?

Comment: I updated my question. I want to save the id of category in my database when i input name of category from searching. Search works fine now as your answer above now i am pause in savin the id of category in my products collection .

Comment: Where/how are you going to save the id of a category? In another category, in another model?

Comment: yes, I want to save the id of category in product model(products collection) so that i can fetch it in product view page as @product.category.name

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29084/discussion-between-regmiprem-and-nyde1319)